# How to set images from sdcard in cardview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

i'm trying to build an app for android. I have a list of android cards inside a recycler view. An example:

[image: example]

Near the Title, Album and Year on the left i have inserted a Imageview space of 100dp x 100dp. The structure of Xml is this http://pastebin.com/t3spdaTS

All the information are in a simple db in sqlite inside the app. I have some images saved in `/sdcard/my_app_name` with a progressive number `1.jpg, 2.jpg, ecc...` where the number is the row inside the db. Now how can i put this images in every card? I have tried to write inside

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getDisks();
cursor.moveToFirst();
...
ImageView iv = (Imageview)find
 while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        count++;

        String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_ARTIST));
        ...
 AlbumCard albumCard = new AlbumCard(0, artist, album, year);
        String path = "sdcard/Warehouse_app/" + count + ".jpg";
        iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
        list.add(albumCard);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```

But the `iv.setImage` give me an `null pointer exception. How can i resolve this problem? Thank you for all.

Comment: You have a problem for finding the image view, Maybe you didn't `inflate` the layout

Comment: Yes, i inflate my layout in my card adapter: http://pastebin.com/qxERGnhk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NullPointerException means that Drawable.createFromPath(path) returns null, there is a problem with the path.

You should get a sdcard path this way

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
    + File.separator + "Warehouse_app" 
    + File.separator + count + ".jpg";
```

Then maybe you should check for this file to exist :

```
    File checkIfFileExists = new File(path);
    if(File.exist()){
         iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
    }
```

Forgot : you should add the permission in AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Wait, maybe it is your iv that is null, could you check? Btw, what is this `ImageView iv = (Imageview)find` ? Shouldn't you use `findViewById(R.id.icon_disk);`?

Comment: OK i understand one thing: if i want load image in a card i must write some instruction in my card adapter (this: http://pastebin.com/rG5zKK06). Now i must pass the path of my image here

Comment: I have solved my problem: i add the instructions for view images in my card adapter and i have corrected the path for the sdcard in all my files. Furthermore i pass to my Cardadapter the absolute path to the img in the sdcard. Thanks all!